# Using Recursion for Additive Persistence

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to solve a Coderbyte challenge, and I'm still trying to fully understand recursion.

Here's the problem: Using the JavaScript language, have the function AdditivePersistence(num) take the num parameter being passed which will always be a positive integer and return its additive persistence which is the number of times you must add the digits in num until you reach a single digit. For example: if num is 2718 then your program should return 2 because 2 + 7 + 1 + 8 = 18 and 1 + 8 = 9 and you stop at 9.

Here's the solution I put into jsfiddle.net to try out:

```
function AdditivePersistence(num) {
    var count=0;
    var sum=0;
    var x = num.toString().split('');
    for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(x[i]); 
    } 
    if(sum.length == 1) {
        return sum;
    }
    else {
        return AdditivePersistence(sum); 
    }
}
alert(AdditivePersistence(19));
```

It tells me that there's too much recursion. Is there another "else" I could put that would basically just re-run the function until the sum was one digit?

Comment: Your function doesn't return the additive persistence. It returns the one-digit number that you get at the end of all the summing. You never increment the counter, which is what you're supposed to be calculating.

Comment: Try stepping through your code with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is that your **if** statement will never evaluate as 'true'. The reason being is that the sum variable is holding a number, and numbers don't have a length function. Also, as 'Barmar' pointed out, you haven't incremented the count variable, and neither are you returning the count variable.

Here's a solution that works using recursion.

```
function AdditivePersistence(num) { 

var result = recursive(String(num).split('').reduce(function(x,y){return parseInt(x) + parseInt(y)}), 1);

    function recursive(n, count){
        c = count;
        if(n < 10)return c;
        else{
          count += 1
          return recursive(String(n).split('').reduce(function(x,y){return parseInt(x) + parseInt(y)}), count)
}
}

return num < 10 ? 0 : result

}
```

Comment: This is correct, however, if num < 10 then recursive function would not need to be called. I would make 'result' store the function and call it in the else clause: return num < 10 ? 0 : result(String(num)....);

Answer (score 0):

To fix the 'too much recursion problem',

```
if(sum.toString().length == 1)
```

However, as the others have said, your implementation does not return the [Additive Persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_a_number). Use James Farrell's answer to solve the Coderbyte challenge.